# Which sites with reviews of backpacker hostels have APIs?

Tags: discussion, tools

I'm always fiddling around with web app programming and I work in a backpacker hostel and I travel around the world each time I save enough money.

So I'm thinking about web apps and mashups I could make.

I'm thinking of something that collects ratings and reviews, just of backpacker hostels for now.

Who knows which websites have APIs?

The websites I know that have either ratings or reviews (or both) are:

- HostelBookers
- Hostelworld
- TripAdvisor

There could be some other sites I don't know of. So far I don't know if even these sites have APIs but I'll do some checking.

Please let me know of other sites that have ratings or reviews of backpacker hostels, and please let me know if any have an API.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't use anithing else Booking.Com API in my developer life.

Useful project with some additional links to the docs:

[Booking.Com API](http://drupal.org/project/booking_com_api)